# Logic to create a number sequence repetitively

Tags: algorithm, math, sequence

I want to achieve below logic

- When user enters number as 0 output should be 1
- when enters number as 1 output should be 21
- when enters number as 2 output should be 41
- when enters number as 3 output should be 61
- when enters number as 4 output should be 81
- when enters number as 5 output should be 1
- when enters number as 6 output should be 21
- when enters number as 7 output should be 41
- when enters number as 8 output should be 61
- when enters number as 9 output should be 81
- when enters number as 10 output should be 1
- when enters number as 11 output should be 21
- when enters number as 12 output should be 41
- when enters number as 13 output should be 61
- when enters number as 14 output should be 81

so basically for every next 5 numbers same sequence should be generated  as it is generated for first five numbers

[sequence example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4arOb.png)
and so on.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user enters the number `x`, the output will be:

```
f(x) = (20 * x + 1) mod 100
```

which can also be represented by:

```
f(x) = (x mod 5) * 20 + 1
```

---

Programmatically speaking:

```
int f(int n){
    return (20 * x + 1) % 100;
}
```

or

```
int f(int n){
    return (x % 5) * 20 + 1;
}
```